If $X$,$Y$ are independent random variables, $\mathbb{E}|X + Y|$ is finite implies $\mathbb{E}|X|$ and $\mathbb{E}|Y|$ are both finite
As the title suggests, I am trying to prove
$$ E|X + Y| < \infty \implies E|X| < \infty $$
for independent $X$ and $Y$ (but not necessarily equal in distribution). Triangular inequality goes the other way, i.e.
$$E|X + Y| \leq E|X| + E|Y|$$
in general. Independence must be the key here somehow.
Something I tried is to prove $E|X - Y| < \infty$. If this is true, then we could use
$$2|X| = |(X + Y) + (X - Y)| \leq |X + Y| + |X - Y|$$
to show that the expectation of $|X|$ is indeed finite. However, I cannot think of a theorem that allows us to conclude the distance is finite if the absolute sum is finite for independent random variables. Any help or insight is appreciated!

Quite trivial if you know Fubini's Theorem. $E|X-y|<\infty$ for some $y$ by that theorem, so $E|X|<\infty$.

@geetha290krm Could you elaborate please? I understand Fubini's theorem only in that one can switch the order of integration if the function is integrable.

$E|X+Y|=\int|X+y|dF_Y(y)<\infty$ which implies that the integrand is finite at at least one point $y$.

Let $\mu_X(E) = \mathbb{P}(X \in E)$ and $\mu_Y(E) = \mathbb{P}(Y \in E)$ denote the law of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Then by the independence of $X$ and $Y$ and the change of variables formula,
$$ \mathbb{E}[|X + Y|] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x+y| \, \mu_X(\mathrm{d}x)\mu_Y(\mathrm{d}y). $$
Since the left-hand side is finite, by Fubini's Theorem,

$\mathbb{E}[|X + y|] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x+y| \, \mu_X(\mathrm{d}x) < \infty$ for $\mu_Y$-almost every $y$, and
$\mathbb{E}[|x + Y|] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x+y| \, \mu_Y(\mathrm{d}y) < \infty$ for $\mu_X$-almost every $x$.

This is enough to conclude that both $X$ and $Y$ have finite expectation.
IF this measure-theoretic language is not comfortable, we may replace integrals with expectations, while taking care of the fact that there is a two-fold of expectations. Indeed, let $\mathbb{E}[|\bullet + Y|]_{\bullet = x}$ be the expectation of $|x + Y|$ with the emphasis on the fact that $x$ will be treated as a constant in the expectation, and let $\mathbb{E}[|X+\bullet|]_{\bullet=y}$ be likewise. Then by the independence, and invoking the law of iterated expectation,
$$ \mathbb{E}[|X + Y|]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[|X + Y| \mid Y]]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[|X + \bullet|]_{\bullet=Y}]$$
Since the left-hand side is finite, we have $\mathbb{E}[|X + \bullet|]_{\bullet=Y} < \infty$ almost surely. From this, we find that $\mathbb{E}[|X + y|] < \infty$ for some $y$, showing $\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$ as well. By interchanging the role of $X$ and $Y$, the integrability of $Y$ is also proved.

Totally agree with this. Could you elaborate on how one can conclude the expectation is finite from the result?

@Neon9357, The final ingredient is to now that, by the triangle inequality, $$\mathbb{E}[|X|] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X+y|]+|-y|. $$ Hope this helps :)
